Can this integral be interpreted as a convolution?
I have a characteristic (indicator) function defined as:
$$
\chi_{[0,1]}(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
1 & \text{if } x \in [0, 1], \\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Now, consider the following integral over the entire real line $ \mathbb{R} $:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \chi_{[0,1]}(x - t) f(x) \, dx
$$
where $ f(x) $ is some given function.
My question is: can this integral be interpreted as the convolution of $ \chi_{[0,1]}(x) $ and $ f(x) $? Specifically, can we express the integral as $ (\chi_{[0,1]} * f)(t) $?
I'm asking because the convolution is usually defined with a similar form, but with the signs reversed in the argument of one of the functions. For example, convolution is typically defined as:
$$
(f * g)(t) := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) g(t - x) \, dx
$$
Does this difference in the sign affect the interpretation of my integral? (E.g. in my question I have $\chi_{[0,1]}(x - t)$ while the definition requires $\chi_{[0,1]}(t-x)$)
Additionally, if I include a factor of $ e^{2\pi i x \xi} $ in the integral, making it:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \chi_{[0,1]}(x - t) f(x) e^{-2\pi i x \xi} \, dx,
$$
can this still be related to a convolution in some way?
Any clarification on these points would be greatly appreciated!

it's the convolution with $\chi_{[0,1]}(-x)$

Let $g(x) = \chi_{[0,1]}(x)$
Your integral $I(t) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x-t) f(x) dx$
Convolution of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is defined as
$$[g(x) * f(x)](t) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(t-x) f(x) dx = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) f(t-x) dx$$
So $I(t)$ is NOT the convolution of $g(x)$ and $f(x)$.
But we can express $g(x-t) = g(-(t-x))$.
With this, we can say $I(t) = [g(-x) * f(x)](t)$.
There is also another operation called cross-correlation which defines your integral $I(t)$. Let's denote cross correlation operation with the symbol $\star$.
$$[g(x) \star f(x)](t) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \overline{g(x-t)} f(x) dx$$
Note that $\overline{()}$ denotes the complex conjugate. However, in our case, $g(x)$ is real and its conjugate is also $g(x)$.
So, we can say $I(t) = [g(x) \star f(x)](t)$.
Next, coming to your second integral,
$$I_{2}(t,\xi) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x-t) f(x) e^{- i 2 \pi x \xi} dx$$.
You can view this as a $[g(-x) * h(x)](t)$, where $h(x) = f(x) e^{- i 2 \pi x \xi}$.
But, $I_{2}(\xi)$ is also famously the Fourier Transform. As such, there are some known properties. One of them is that Fourier Transform of prodcut of two functions is the convolution of Fourier Transform of the functions being multiplied.
$I_{2}(\xi) = (\widehat{g(x-t)} * \widehat{f(x)})(\xi)$
and
$$\widehat{g(x-t)} = e^{- i 2 \pi t \xi} \widehat{g(x)}$$
Noting that indicator function has a closed form Fourier Transform in terms of sinc function, you can further simplify.
